# Biovars (dismo package) with data from DWD

Tags: r, dismo

I am new to R and I tried to calculate the bioclimatic variables with the `biovars` function from the `dismo` package for weather data from the DWD (Deutscher Wetterdienst).
I need those variables for specific inventory plots, and so my first idea was to extract the monthly precipitation and temperature min and max for each inventory plot, and then calculate the bioclimatic variables for each plot.
My output of this process is a data frame, which is not useable as input for  `biovars`.
Now I am struggling to get a valid input format for the `biovars` function (vector, matrix, RasterStack) either out of this data frame or with the original data from DWD (and then extract the plots later).

This is my script for the min temperature per month:

```
index <- indexFTP(folder="monthly/air_temperature_min", base=gridbase)
index <- index[-(1471:1472)] # exclude description files, monthly at the end of the list
index <- index[as.numeric(substr(index,71,76)) >=201001] # after year 2010/01
index

# download & read data:
tempminM <- dataDWD(index, base=gridbase, joinbf=TRUE)
names(tempminM) <- substr(names(tempminM), 71, 76)

# terra raster:
tempminM_stack <- terra::rast(tempminM)
crs(tempminM_stack) <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs"

# Extract values
tempminM_pred <- extract(tempminM_stack, sf_coord_plots_gk3)
tempminM_pred <- cbind(tempminM_pred, sf_coord_plots_gk3)
```

`

tempminM is a list.
tempminM_stack is a SpatRaster

I tried to get a Rasterstack from the tempminM_stack , but it's all NA.

```
# to stack
tempminM_stack_stack <- terra::as.raster(tempminM_stack)
tempminM_stack_stack <- as.matrix(tempminM_stack_stack)
```

I would be very happy to get a hint!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi I.Klein, welcome to Stack Overflow. I had some trouble following your example because I do not know what `sf_coord_plots_gk3` is. I was able to get a list of all of the non-missing values using `cells(tempminM_stack)` and then `xyFromCell(tempminM_stack, *cellnumber*)` where *cellnumber* is one of the values from `cells`. An example is `xyFromCell(tempminM_stack, 182)`. I could get a vector or matrix of non-missing values using `extract(tempminM_stack, y=matrix(c(3461915, 6103001), nrow=1, byrow=T))`, where `c(3461915, 6103001)` are the results from `cells(tempminM_stack)[1]`.

Comment: This result can go into `biovars` because it is a vector or matrix, your choice. Is it possible that you have a problem when you specify the location in the `terra::extract` function? I don't know any of these packages, but I was able to get a non-missing result from `extract` that worked. This is why I am asking about the values in `sf_coord_plots_gk3`.